# Redirect after fetch to results page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch

I have a searchBar component on my index page in next.js App:

```
type WeatherData = {
  location: {
    name: string;
  };
  current: {
    temp_c: number;
  };
};

const SearchBar = ({
  setSearchData
}: {
  setSearchData: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<WeatherData | null>>;
}) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')

  // If there was a "real" API search term would be needed for request too
  const handleSearch = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const apiUrl = 'http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=';
    const apiKey = '*************';

    const url = `${apiUrl}${apiKey}&q=${encodeURIComponent(searchTerm)}&aqi=no`;
    try {
      const searchData: WeatherData = await fetchData(url);
      
      console.log('Weather object:', searchData);
      
      setSearchData(searchData);
      // Redirect to search results page
      const searchResultUrl = `/searchResults?q=${encodeURIComponent(
        searchTerm,
      )}&p=1`
      router.push(searchResultUrl)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching search results:', error)
    }
  }

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSearch} className="flex">
      <label htmlFor="search-bar" className="sr-only">
        Search statista
      </label>
      <input
        id="search-bar"
        name="search"
        type="search"
        required
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={handleChange}
        className="h-14 md:w-[500px] sm:w-full rounded-l-md border-2 border-skyblue bg-white px-3.5 py-2 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none"
        placeholder="Find statistics, forecasts and reports"
      />
      {/* area label here isn't really  needed as the button already has it's content*/}
      <button
        type="submit"
        className="h-14 md:w-[200px] rounded-r-md bg-skyblue border-2 border-skyblue text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 focus:outline-none flex items-center justify-center"
        aria-label="Search"
      >
      {/* svg typically needs title and description and aria-labledby, referring to the title. Maybe use role graphics-symbol as it is an icon*/}
        <span className="hidden md:inline mr-2 font-sans">Statista search</span>
        <svg
          width="14"
          height="14"
          viewBox="0 0 14 14"
          fill="none"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          role="img"
          aria-labelledby="search-icon"
        >
          <title id="search-icon">Search Icon</title>
          <path
            fillRule="evenodd"
            clipRule="evenodd"
            d="M0 5.83335C0 7.38044 0.614573 8.86418 1.70854 9.9581C2.80249 11.0521 4.28621 11.6667 5.8333 11.6667C6.98558 11.6667 8.10271 11.3258 9.04983 10.6998L12.0084 13.6583C12.464 14.1139 13.2027 14.1139 13.6583 13.6583C14.1139 13.2027 14.1139 12.464 13.6583 12.0084L10.6997 9.04982C11.3257 8.10272 11.6666 6.98561 11.6666 5.83335C11.6666 4.28625 11.052 2.80251 9.95802 1.70855C8.8641 0.614578 7.38038 0 5.8333 0C4.28621 0 2.80249 0.614578 1.70854 1.70855C0.614573 2.80251 0 4.28625 0 5.83335ZM3.35844 8.30822C2.70207 7.65184 2.33332 6.76161 2.33332 5.83335C2.33332 4.90509 2.70207 4.01485 3.35844 3.35847C4.01481 2.70209 4.90504 2.33334 5.8333 2.33334C6.76155 2.33334 7.65178 2.70209 8.30815 3.35847C8.96453 4.01485 9.33327 4.90509 9.33327 5.83335C9.33327 6.76161 8.96453 7.65184 8.30815 8.30822C7.65178 8.9646 6.76155 9.33335 5.8333 9.33335C4.90504 9.33335 4.01481 8.9646 3.35844 8.30822Z"
            fill="white"
          />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default SearchBar
```

So as you see, my searchBar redirects to a searchResults page:

```
type WeatherData = {
  location: {
    name: string;
  };
  current: {
    temp_c: number;
  };
};

const SearchResults = () => {
  const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState<WeatherData | null>(null);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
  const [itemsPerPage, setItemsPerPage] = useState(10)
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
  const searchTerm = searchParams.get('q')
  // get to a desired page by changing url params
  const requestedPage = searchParams.get('p')

  // get to a desired page by changing url params
  useEffect(() => {
    if (requestedPage) {
      setCurrentPage(parseInt(requestedPage, 10))
    }
  }, [requestedPage])

  // Calculate number of pages for pagination
  // const totalPages = Math.ceil(searchData?.length / itemsPerPage)

  // Get current items for pagination
  const indexOfLastItem = currentPage * itemsPerPage
  const indexOfFirstItem = indexOfLastItem - itemsPerPage
  //const currentItems = searchData.slice(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem)
  console.log(searchData)
  return (
    <>
      <div className="bg-royalblue md:px-100 h-[150px]">
        <div className="pt-10">
          <Image
            src="statista_logo.svg"
            alt="Statista Logo"
            width={200}
            height={50}
            className="lg:absolute top-10 left-40 mx-auto"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="h-[100px] flex items-center justify-center px-10 bg-white">
        <SearchBar setSearchData={setSearchData} />
      </div>
      <div role="status" aria-live="polite" className="h-[100px] bg-lightgrey lg:px-40 px-10 font-sans py-7">
        {/* <h2 className="text-spacegray font-bold" aria-label={`Total results: ${searchData.length}`}>
          TOTAL RESULTS: <span className="text-royalblue font-thin">{searchData.length}</span>
        </h2> */}
        <h2 className="text-spacegray font-bold" aria-label={`Search term: ${searchTerm}`}>
          SEARCH TERM: <span className="text-royalblue font-thin">{searchTerm}</span>
        </h2>
      </div>
      {searchData ? (
        <div className="lg:px-40 px-10 bg-white py-10">
          <div className="space-y-4 bg-white">
            <div className="text-skyblue font-bold font-sans">
              {searchData.location.name}
            </div>
            <div className="text-royalblue overflow-ellipsis overflow-hidden whitespace-nowrap font-sans font-thin">
              {searchData.current.temp_c}
            </div>
          </div>
            
          
          <div className="px-48 bg-white py-10">
            <Pagination
              currentPage={currentPage}
              totalPages={20}
              setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>No search results yet.</p>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default SearchResults
```

My searchData is however null on initial load, if I use searchBar on my searchResult page, searchData is loaded correctly. I've been searching for a while and the only easy solution I got, to fetch again (or maybe just) on the searchResults page. Any other way to fetch and pass data from searchBar to searchResults including initial load? And what's the standart? Where to fetch?